# Dynamic email subjects with Elmah?

Tags: asp.net, elmah

I'm using the errorMail functionality of [Elmah](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) to send an email when ASP.NET encounters an error. It allows you to configure the SMTP settings as well as hard-code a sender, recipient, and subject.

My question is: **can I use a dynamic subject**? Specifically, I would like to use the Exception.Message property as my subject, so that I can tell what the error is about just from the subject line of the email.

There is no documentation, and from a quick scan of the source code it looks impossible without modifying the code, but I thought I would ask the question anyways.

Relevant source code:

- [ErrorMailModule.cs](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/trunk/src/Elmah/ErrorMailModule.cs)
- [ErrorMailHtmlFormatter.cs](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/trunk/src/Elmah/ErrorMailHtmlFormatter.cs)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Doh! Answer is on [line 454 of ErrorMailModule.cs](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/trunk/src/Elmah/ErrorMailModule.cs#454):

```
string subjectFormat = Mask.EmptyString(this.MailSubjectFormat, "Error ({1}): {0}");
mail.Subject = string.Format(subjectFormat, error.Message, error.Type)
                .Replace('\r', ' ')
                .Replace('\n', ' ');
```

#### You can use {0} for the message and {1} for the type.

Comment: you link didnt work for me. but this one did...http://code.google.com/p/elmah/source/browse/src/Elmah/ErrorMailModule.cs#452

Comment: why is it `"Error ({1}): {0}"` instead of `"Error ({0}): {1}"`

Answer (score 2):

I've changed the email subject from the web.config file in this way:

```
<errorMail from="..." subject="Some subject: {0}">
```

where {0} will be the exception message.

You can check this article for more details http://weblogs.asp.net/jeffwids/format-the-email-subject-in-the-elmah-error-logging-module